# Piping "find" results to Azure CLI

Tags: find

I am trying to use the `find` command to find a list of specific files I then want to pipe each file to another command...with the other command being the Azure CLI command line. I tried using the command below:

`find /folder -name exclude1 -prune -o -name exclude2 -prune -o -name *.bicep -print -exec az bicep build {}`

but this just throws the error `find: missing argument to -exec`

Can I make an array out of the `find` results that I can then use in a for loop to pass each element into the `az bicep build` command?

BTW...without the `-exec` parameter, the `find` command returns the result set I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it returns `find: missing argument to -exec` is because the `-exec` parameter needs to be terminated, either with `+` or `\;`. The `+` syntax will pass as many arguments to a single command as possible, like `az bicep build file1 file2 file3`. The `\;` syntax will run a new command for each file with only one file as the parameter, which is probably what you need.

Depending on your shell and the files in your current directory, it will likely try to parse `*.bicep` and possibly `{}`, which should instead be passed to `find`. These should be quoted as well, just to be safe.

The following command should do what you need:

```
find /folder -name exclude1 -prune -o -name exclude2 -prune -o -name '*.bicep' -print -exec az bicep build '{}' \;
```

Comment: That worked perfect...thanks for responding